# jQuery DnD. How to pass data associated with an element being dragged?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

There is a list / a table of items (I believe it doesn't matter now). They are made draggable with use of jQuery. I need to set some data associated with an item element being dragged and to be able to extract it from event in "drop" handler of droppable element.

I was trying to use `dataTransfer` property with its `setData()` function but the property is not available on both sides.

Here is simplefied example: http://jsfiddle.net/x52ue9ae/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that this is not HTML5 drag-n-drop, jQueryUI implements pure javascript drag and drop using mousedown/mousemove/mouseup events. There are no `dataTransfer` mechanism involved at all.

Instead you should set data property using jQuery to the drag-element:

```
$(function(){
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        start: function(e) {
            $(this).data('id', 3);
        }
    });
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(e, ui) {
            var id = ui.draggable.data('id');
            console.log(id);
        }
    })
});
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/x52ue9ae/2/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use the [dataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) is an html5 drag and drop feature which is not used by jQuery DnD.

You can use the [data api](http://api.jquery.com/data/) to store data in the dragged element and use access it in the drop handler like

```
$(function () {
    $(".draggable").draggable({
        start: function (e, ui) {
            $(this).data('x', 3)
        }
    });
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function (e, ui) {
            console.log('x', ui.draggable.data('x'))
        }
    })
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/z77e1t76/)